# SQL: How to group by and get the max of two different columns

Tags: sql

This is my first time posting, so I'm probably breaking all the formatting rules.. Here's an example of my table

```
    product     category  cost  date(in julian)       time(in julian)
    -----------------------------------------------------------------
    1            222      12      120223                125418
    1            222      32      120223                125645
    1            222      11      120112                145411
```

I'm trying to group by product and category and grab the cost that was created the most recently.

As an example, in this case I would like to be pulling back 32. I'm doing a max on both date and time, and as I'm sure you know I am getting back a max date of 120223 (good), however a max time of 145411 (bad).

How can I get the max date records (leaving me with all of the 120223 records), then get the max time OF those records?

Here's an example of what I've been working on:

```
select product, category, max(date), max(time)
from t1
group by product, category
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

One method is a correlated subquery:

```
select t1.*
from t1
where t1.time = (select max(tt1.time)
                 from t1 tt1
                 where tt1.product = t1.product and tt1.category = t1.category
                );
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select *
from 
(
    select product, category, cost, date, time, row_number() over (partition by product, category order by date desc, time desc) as rn 
    from t1
) t0
where rn = 1
```